# How to transform a set of fasta sequences into a set of Xstrings in R

Tags: r

I am struggling on how to transform a set of fasta sequences into a set of XStrings or DNAstrings.

I was trying to read my fasta file (with several sequences) into a list of sequences with read.fasta. If I worked just with one sequence I would be able to transform it to a DNAString (with DNAString function), but as I have more than one sequence I don't achieve that.

As an example:

```
my_sequences<-read.fasta(sequences.fasta)
my sequences 

$`1:20000-20009`
[1] "agtcgctag"
attr(,"name")
[1] "1:20000-20009"
attr(,"Annot")
[1] ">1:20000-20009"
attr(,"class")
[1] "SeqFastadna"

$`1:30000-30010`
[1] "aggggggggggca"
attr(,"name")
[1] "1:30000-30010"
attr(,"Annot")
[1] "1:30000-30010"
attr(,"class")
[1] "SeqFastadna"

.
.
.
```

Now I am not able to transform this set into a set of XStrings or DNAStrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `readDNAStringSet` in Biostrings:

```
my_sequences<-readDNAStringSet(sequences.fasta)
```

For example:

```
fa = c(">1:20000-20009","agtcgctag",">1:30000-30010","aggggggggggca")
writeLines(fa,"test.fa")
library(Biostrings)
my_sequences<-readDNAStringSet("test.fa")

my_sequences
  A DNAStringSet instance of length 2
    width seq                                               names               
[1]     9 AGTCGCTAG                                         1:20000-20009
[2]    13 AGGGGGGGGGGCA                                     1:30000-30010
```

Each subset is a DNAString:

```
my_sequences[[1]]
  9-letter "DNAString" instance
seq: AGTCGCTAG
```